# Browsing images like in gallery (by swiping them)

Tags: xaml, android-viewpager, uwp, image-gallery, windows-10-universal

I need to show images downloaded from the Internet in a convenient way (number of jpgs is not fixed, it is usually between 10 and 30). I thought I could use swiping like in gallery app.

On Android I could just use `ViewPager`. What is Windows equivalent for this?

In earlier version I used `controls:MediaViewer` but it doesn't seem to be supported in Windows 10.

What is the right way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flip view control for displaying images in a collection. You create a DataTemplate to specify the look of the items. Further details and an example can be found at this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/flipview

Comment: Thanks! That is what I was looking for